# How to add a div class to menu link?

Tags: 7, routes, media, theming

I would like to add a specific *class* to specific *menu item*, so that the menu item would show an image on **hover**.

Basically I want to implement this in a menu item link:

```
<div class="thumbnails">
<a href="#">Some_name<span><img src="http://www........jpg" alt="image1" height="30%" width="30%" /></span></a>
</div>
```

I have tried [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module but I couldn't specified a class I wanted to add. Is there any other way how to do it please?

Answer (score 1):

[Menu CSS Names](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_css_names)

> This is a very simple module that takes the link text of each drupal
>   menu item and adds it as a css class name to the menu's element.
>   Using these class names, each menu item can be styled separately with
>   css. This is also very useful for css sprite techniques.
>
> There are no admin settings for this module, it starts doing its work
>   once the module is enabled. All caches are automatically cleared at
>   this time also. This module works with menus in blocks (including
>   Primary Links) and menus in themes (menus that are enabled from the
>   theme's configuration page).

Comment: Thank you Adi for your answer, i tried Menu CSS Names module, but when i tried to apply css code for showing an image when hover over the link it completely messed up whole page. The Menu HTML module allows me to input class in link title but it's still not what i wanted. Maybe the mistake is in my CSS code but i dont know how to insert it in comment, can you please help me with it ? Thank you very much

Comment: create a hierarchy from main menu class to your class then apply css on it

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean, can you please show me how? Thank you

Comment: #main-id .sub-menu class .your definedclass like this

Answer (score 0):

You could use [theme_menu_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7):

```
function MY_THEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

  // Add a div wrapper to my special link.
  $prefix = '';
  $suffix = '';
  if ($element['#href'] == 'foo/bar') {
    $prefix = '<div class="thumbnails">';
    $suffix = '</div>';
  }

  return $prefix . '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>{$suffix}\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tyler, I've been trying to add theme_menu_link() function to template.php all day but it doesn't seem to make any difference in menu structure. I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your Drupal cache and check once. Further, you can check [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) link for your purpose.